# How to open Material UI Menu component to the left instead of the right?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I've made a dropdown component with Material UI's Menu component, but by default the menu component opens to the right. I need it to actually open to the left.

I've tried styling it, and I can end up getting it to move with margins, but I'm looking for something more reliable. I'm surprised there isn't a prop for this to be honest.

[currently, my dropdown menu opens like this - not good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EDOu.png)

I want it to start there, just open the other direction. Any help appreciated!

My code is below:
Component

```
function DropDown({
  dropDownMeta,
  style = { container: {}, icon: {} },
  icon = <MenuIcon style={{ ...style.icon }} />
}: DropDownProps): ReactElement {
  const [menuAnchor, setMenuAnchor] = useState<null | HTMLElement>(null)

  const handleMenuClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    setMenuAnchor(event.currentTarget)
  }

  const handleMenuClose = () => {
    setMenuAnchor(null)
  }
  const classes = useStyles()
  return (
    <Box style={{ ...style.container }}>
      <StyledIconButton
        style={{ ...style.buttonContainer }}
        onClick={handleMenuClick}
      >
        {icon}
      </StyledIconButton>
      <Menu
        anchorEl={menuAnchor}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(menuAnchor)}
        onClose={handleMenuClose}
        className={classes.root}
        style={menuStyles as CSSProperties}
        // getContentAnchorEl={null}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "left",
        }}
      >
        {dropDownMeta.map((item, i) => {
          const { label, callback, bottomDivider } = item
          return (
            <Box key={`Item${i}`} onClick={handleMenuClose}>
              <StyledMenuItem onClick={callback}>{label}</StyledMenuItem>
              {bottomDivider && <Divider />}
            </Box>
          )
        })}
      </Menu>
    </Box>
  )
}

export default DropDown
```

styles

```
dropDown: {
    menu: {
      position: "absolute",
      top: 35
    },
    menuItem: {
      fontSize: 12,
      padding: 5,
      minWidth: 250
    },
    menuIconBtn: {
      fontSize: 31,
      position: "relative",
      top: 1,
      padding: 0
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add and configure the property `transformOrigin` to the Menu component.  This is not shown in the Menu API docs, but you can read about it in the [Popover API](https://material-ui.com/api/popover/) docs.

The description of `transformOrigin` from the Popover API is

> This is the point on the anchor where the popover's anchorEl will attach to. This is not used when the anchorReference is 'anchorPosition'.
> Options: vertical: [top, center, bottom]; horizontal: [left, center, right].

This example is just a simplification of [Material-UI's customized menus demo](https://material-ui.com/components/menus/#customized-menus).

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button, Menu, MenuItem } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function CustomizedMenus() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: 200 }}>
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleClick}>
        Open Menu
      </Button>
      <Menu
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={!!anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        getContentAnchorEl={null}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "center",
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "right",
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem style={{ backgroundColor: "pink" }}>
          Long bit of text so we can see left/right...
        </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: image of menu item clicked and showing placeholder text]

Comment: Anchor playground is very useful for this kind of configurations https://material-ui.com/components/popover/#anchor-playground

Comment: This looks exactly like what I'm looking for thank you!

Comment: About why specifying Popover props works here: in Menu API doc https://material-ui.com/api/menu/ it says `Any other props supplied will be provided to the root element (Popover)`